# Can SAS Enterprise Miner - Cluster node - take coordinate matrix as input?

Tags: machine-learning, sas, cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means

I am using SAS proc distance to create a distance matrix. I wanted to know if SAS EM cluster node can use this matrix to create perform K mean clustering?

Answer (score 0):

K-means *must* be used with squared euclidean. Because technically, it minimizes *variances*, not distances.

Furthermore, it can obviously *not* be used with distance matrixes, because it does not need object-to-object distances, but object-to-mean distances (and the means change).